# Insert space at the beginning of line matched with lookarounds

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

I am trying to add spaces at the beginning of lines matched with look arounds. Here is a sample text:

```
This is my 
first sentence
with 2 lines
that have to be indented. 

This is my 
second sentence
with 2 lines
that have to be indented.
```

and this is the output I want to get:

```
This is my 
    first sentence
    with 2 lines
that have to be indented. 

This is my 
    second sentence
    with 2 lines
that have to be indented.
```

I have tried look around with this:
`(?<=This is my)(.*?)(?=\nthat)`

But, I am not able to match the start of line with `^`. That is, `(?<=This is my)(^)(?=\nthat)` does not work.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yznLZJ/1)

TIA!

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

```
(.+?\n)(.+?\n)(.+?\n)(.+?\n)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Ryb3pR/1

It seems like it would be more easily understandable to to this with some code instead of with regex.

Answer (score 0):

If a quantifier is supported in a lookbehind assertion (Like .NET, newer Javascript engine or Python PyPi regex module), and you want to match any number of lines,  you could use:

```
(?<=^This is my.*\n(?!that\b)(?:.*\n(?!that\b))*).*
```

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind to assert what is to the left is

  - `^` Start of string
  - `This is my.*\n(?!that\b)` Match the first line, and assert not `that` on the next line
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `.*\n(?!that\b)` Match the whole line including the newline, and assert not `that` on the next
  - `)*` Close non capture group
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `.*` Match the whole line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/otgCeR/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=^This is my.*\n(?!that\b)(?:.*\n(?!that\b))*).*/gm;
const str = `This is my 
first sentence
with 2 lines
that have to be indented. 

This is my 
second sentence
testing
with 3 lines
that have to be indented. 
test

This is my 
that have to be indented. `;
console.log(str.replace(regex, `    $&`));
```

There is no language listed, but another option is to use a 2 capture groups, and add the indenting to all the lines in the second group.

The pattern captures the starting line in group 1, followed by capturing all lines in group 2 that do not start with `that`

```
^(This is my.*)((?:\n(?!that\b).*)*)(?=\nthat\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gAPJpf/1)

For example using Javascript:

```js
const regex = /^(This is my.*)((?:\n(?!that\b).*)*)(?=\nthat\b)/gm;
const str = `This is my 
first sentence
with 2 lines
that have to be indented. 

This is my 
second sentence
testing
with 3 lines
that have to be indented. 
test

This is my 
that have to be indented. `;
console.log(str
  .replace(regex, (m, g1, g2) => g1 + g2
    .split('\n').map(s => '    ' + s)
    .join('\n'))
);
```